# Vulnerable Libraries issue unable to publish new update android app version in play console

Tags: javascript, jquery

Vulnerable Libraries issue unable to publish new update android app version in play console I am getting error. JavaScript jquery 1.11.2 SNYK-npm:jquery:20110606,
SNYK-npm:jquery:20150627,
SNYK-JS-JQUERY-174006 assets/jquery.min.js

Regards

Chandan Sharma

Comment: https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-JQUERY-174006

Comment: You need to update jQuery, download a new version, and replace assets/jquery.min.js. There are no other fix.

Comment: Consider updating your question so that it has a question. It is not clear if you want an explanation of the error encountered or guidance on how to prevent it.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you've shared suggests that your app's assets include versions of jQuery that are susceptible to security risks.

To tackle this issue, it's crucial to update the jQuery library in your project to a version that is free from known vulnerabilities. The versions highlighted in the error message, specifically "1.11.2," "20110606," and "20150627," are known to have security flaws.

2. **Replace the vulnerable file:** Remove the compromised version of "jquery.min.js" from your app's assets directory and substitute it with the updated version.
3. **Test your app:** After updating the jQuery library, conduct a comprehensive functional test to confirm that your app operates as expected and that the vulnerability issue has been resolved.
4. **Rebuild and re-upload your app:** After testing, generate a new build of your Android app with the updated jQuery library and upload it to the Google Play Console.

Please note that this process may necessitate updating other plugins or dependencies that rely on the outdated version of jQuery. Therefore, ensure to check if any other components in your app are dependent on a specific version of jQuery and update them as needed.

Moreover, it's vital to regularly review and update your app's dependencies to ensure that you are using the most recent versions that come with security patches and bug fixes.